# How to delete my root node (clearing my XML data file) with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

This is my sample XML file.

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
         <users>

           <uploader ID="13">
               <Name>Mun</Name>
               <Photos_Uploaded>6</Photos_Uploaded>
           </uploader>

           <uploader ID="12">
               <Name>ris</Name>
               <Photos_Uploaded>10</Photos_Uploaded>
           </uploader>

         </users>
```

I have tried this but it didn't work at all.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("photo.xml");
          var y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("uploader")[0];
          var z=y.parentNode();
          z.removeChild(y);
    </script>
```

What i want to do is clear the whole XML file before appending new data and i want it to be as transparent as possible, hence using Javascript, i will call it externally. I know i can do it with DOM too though javascript is my preferred option. However if any of the java answers do not work, i wouldnt mind using DOM.

Comment: If you're looking to begin appending nodes to an empty XML document - starting with the root node - then why don't you just start out with a clean slate and create a brand new document in your language/context of choice?

Comment: The document is not empty. It has some elements which i need to clear. In fact, i need to clear the whole file first.

Comment: I know am Off topic but java != javascript and i hate when people say that ,

Comment: Corrected. Thanks. I want it to be in javascript.

Comment: You're manipulating the resulting DOM of the XML file. To manipulate the actual file, you'll need to write to the file. Think of it as loading text from a file into a variable. While you can then change the value of the variable, that won't change the contents of the file.

Writing to a local file from Javascript in a browser (without using Java, Flash or other plugins) is not possible. Writing to something on the network will need server-side work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "xmlDoc" is a DOM Document Object (e.g., retrieved by `responseXML` from an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest)) something like this should work:

```
xmlDoc.removeChild(xmlDoc.firstChild);
```

Comment: Wait, so you want to clear the *file itself* and not just the DOM Document object?

Answer (score 0):

If xmlDoc was correctly loaded in you code then you have only one simple bug - parentNode is a  property not method so correct usage is:

```
var z = y.parentNode; // without parentheses here
z.removeChild(y);
```